# i am trying to insert a table inside the canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

iI am trying to insert a table inside the canvas like in MS word.

Can I directly insert the rows and cells into the canvas to create a table using javascript code with `insertRow()` and `insertCell()` methods?

Answer (score 0):

The best thing to do is to place your div elsewhere and then position it on top of the canvas. For example:

```
<canvas style="width: 400px; height: 400px">

</canvas>
<table style="position: relative; width: 400px; top: -400">

</table>
```

Then you can use your javascript to insert elements into the table, just like you would any other table. It'll appear on top of the canvas.

Comment: Thank you very much . Can i have the sample example please.

Comment: You'll have to give me more information about what you are doing. It is very simple, just a table (or anything else) positioned on top of the canvas. The code above sets it up.

Comment: you wanted to make the position `absolute` I suppose. And add `px` after `-400`.